# Check in every row of a df which columns of a column list have the value True and mark them in a "Test" column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe which contains the values True/False in certain columns that are in a column list.

For every column in the column list in the dataframe, for every row check if all the values of the columns in the list are False.

If they are false write in a new "Test" column "No Errors".

Else if there are True values in at least 1 column write the name of the column(s) with the True value followed by underscores.

**Example**

col_list = ['col1','col2', ... col'10')

In the first row  of the df if col1 and col8 in col_list are True, write in the test column "Col1_Col8".

In the second row  of the df if all cols in col_list are False, write in the test column "No Errors".

Comment: `f col1 and col8 in col_list are True, write in the test column "Col1_Col10".` - do you think `Col1_Col8` ?

Comment: It should be col1_col8 thank you fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) for matrix multplication with columns names from list:

```
np.random.seed(123)

f = lambda x: f'col{x+1}'
df = (pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([True, False], size=(5,10), p=(0.2, 0.8)))
        .rename(columns=f))
# print (df)
    
            
col_list = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7', 'col8', 'col9','col10']

df['Test'] = df[col_list].dot(pd.Index(col_list) + '_').str[:-1].replace('', 'No Errors')
print (df)

    col1   col2   col3   col4   col5   col6   col7   col8   col9  col10  \
0  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False   
1  False  False  False   True  False  False   True   True  False  False   
2  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False   
3   True  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False   
4  False   True  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False   

             Test  
0       No Errors  
1  col4_col7_col8  
2       No Errors  
3            col1  
4            col2
```

Testing boolean columns:

```
print (df[col_list].dtypes)
col1     bool
col2     bool
col3     bool
col4     bool
col5     bool
col6     bool
col7     bool
col8     bool
col9     bool
col10    bool
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! I get the following error -----------------------------------------DataFrame.dot(self, other)
   1612     return self._constructor_sliced(np.dot(lvals, rvals), index=left.index)
   1613 elif isinstance(rvals, (np.ndarray, Index)):
-> 1614     result = np.dot(lvals, rvals)
   1615     if result.ndim == 2:
   1616         return self._constructor(result, index=left.index)

File <__array_function__ internals>:200, in dot(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Comment: @ΘοδωρήςΠάλλης - there was typo, need `str[:-1]`, can you check edited answer?

Comment: Thank you I have :

----> 1 df1['Test'] = df1[col_list].dot(pd.Index(col_list) + '_').str[:-1].replace('', 'No Errors')

DataFrame.dot(self, other)
   1612     return self._constructor_sliced(np.dot(lvals, rvals), index=left.index)
   1613 elif isinstance(rvals, (np.ndarray, Index)):
-> 1614     result = np.dot(lvals, rvals)
   1615     if result.ndim == 2:
   1616         return self._constructor(result, index=left.index)

File <__array_function__ internals>:200, in dot(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Comment: @ΘοδωρήςΠάλλης - Are all columns from `col_list` boolean like in answer? Are all columns names from `col_list` strings?

Comment: @ΘοδωρήςΠάλλης - You can test by `print (df[col_list].dtypes)`, added ouput to answer - need all boolean

Comment: I checked again and the values True and False are not boolean but strings!

Comment: @ΘοδωρήςΠάλλης - Then use `df[col_list] = df[col_list].eq('True')`

Comment: Thanks it works as desired!

Comment: May I add some additional scenarios ?

Comment: @ΘοδωρήςΠάλλης - Sure, can you be more specific?

Comment: Thanks do I need to add them to this question or may I open another question?

Comment: @ΘοδωρήςΠάλλης - I think best create new question. Be free reuse data  sample from my answer.

Comment: Thank you this is the new question. The account is my business account. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75789542/check-in-every-row-of-a-df-which-columns-of-a-column-list-have-the-value-true-an